# Cannot get Qt Creator to list available Android SDK

Tags: android, qt

I've just installed Qt Android 5.7.1 in a machine using Debian Jessie and KDE. I've had previously installed (and also compiled and run) Android Studio.

When configuring Qt Creator I selected the SDK folder as the folder for the SDK of Android Studio. (I have done this before in other computers before with no problem). However when I try to build my app I get the android--1 not found error. And as it turns out when I go to Projects -> Build For Android there is a Section named Build Android APK. Here there is a combo box for Android Build SDK and it is empty.

I went to the Sdk folder and then to tools/bin and run the sdkmanager to list the SDK only to get the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/android/sdklib/tool/SdkManagerCli : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
```

Any ideas on how can I get to compile with Android on this system? There are a few threads and post with this problem, but they either have no solution or are in windows environments...